# Solution to SVN Error: No such file commit-email.pl

Tags: svn, hook, tortoisesvn

I received the following error when committing via TortoiseSVN:

Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 127) with output: 
Error: /home/svnRepos/proj/Blah/hooks/post-commit: line 52:
/usr/share/doc/subversion-1.4.2/tools/hook-scripts/commit-email.pl: No
such file or directory
...

I looked into this and noticed that there is now the following path:
/usr/share/doc/subversion-1.6.11/tools/hook-scripts/

In that folder there is a commit-email.rb file.

Any chance you might know why our SVN is trying to look back in the 1.42
folder when sending out the email hook?

Any other suggestions about how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to your post-commit file ( /home/svnRepos/proj/SRP/hooks/post-commit ) line 52, edit the reference to the commit-email.pl and change it to the newer script.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  That was the problem.  I also had to copy over an old commit-email.pl~ file from the subversion-1.4.2 hook folder to the subversion-1.6.11 hook folder.  I'm not sure how all the files in the 1.4.2 folder were deleted.  Yikes.  Thanks again.